# Тестирование в phpUnit Mock-объектами

Tags: php, тестирование, phpunit

Допустим, в тестируемом классе есть несколько публичных методов:

```
class Sample {
    function method1() {
        return [1,2,3];
    }
    function method2($id) {
        return (in_array($id, $this->method1()));
    }
}
```

`method2` зависит от результатов `method1`.

Создаю тесты для первого метода, в котором гоняю его с разными наборами исходных значений. Потом берусь за тесты для второго метода, в котором эмулирую результаты работы первого:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Sample::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['method1'])
    ->getMock();

$mock->method('method1')->willReturn([1,2,3]);

$this->assertTrue($mock->method2(1));
```

А теперь вопрос:

Когда-нибудь в далеком будущем в результате рефакторинга я решаю, что результат работы первого метода должен выводиться в виде `[1=>true,2=>true,3=>true]`. С тестами первого метода всё в порядке, они не пройдут и я сразу решу эту проблему. Но тесты второго получают эмулированные исходные данные, которые уже неактуальны.

Какая есть возможность/стратегия обезопасить себя от такой ситуации?

Comment: Рискну предположить что если Вы рефакторите какой-то метод, от которого зависит что-то, Вы зависимое так же поправите на корректную обработку, иначе всё упадёт. А там и тесты вместе с ними.

Comment: @Skyrocker ну если следовать методологии TDD, то тесты первичны и писать код нужно так, чтобы исполнялись тесты. А если надеяться, что я помню что от чего у меня зависит - то зачем мне вообще тесты?

Comment: Править внешние методы - всегда риск. В подобных случаях стоит сделать что-то вроде хранилища, где все методы и их возможные возвращения. Там поправите и все остальные, которые возвраты для проверок берут из хранилища, упадут с ошибкой.